# Add price with carton and price without carton

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute, price, shopping-cart-price-rules

I have products such as gaming tables and chairs. I want to add two prices to them: a price with carton and a price without carton. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "Customizable options" in order to allow the customer to choose if they want to add this option or not.

Here is an example of a configuration you might need :

[image: customizable options]

For other product, you will be able to click on "Import options" on the top right corner to "copy paste" this "carton option".